# How to organise Spring project

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

I'm vey new to developing in `Spring`.
I want to develop a project, but I don't know how to structure it.

I want to develop an `application` that I can use on the `web` and on `mobile`.

A app eqaul to mine idea would be this stackoverflow website.
I want everything to be visible on the `web`, but i want to develop a `mobile application` that can accces/edit the data.

I hope someone can give me a idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Spring question.

What you want is a REST API and two clients : a webapp and a mobile app (or just a responsive webapp which fits on mobile devices).

The REST API as well as the clients could be written with any framework. I don't know if Spring has mobile built-in features.

**EDIT**

You can have 2 controllers within the same webapp : one controller serving request at URI `/rest/...` for example and another controller serving JSPs for the web.
Or even as you stated a single controller which return HTML (via JSP) or JSON depending on the request.

Have a look at http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc (old link, there might be a newer up to date link..)

Comment: Do i need to create 2 seperate programs, or can I let the controller return json for api, and a jsp for web?

Comment: You can have 2 controllers within the same webapp. One controller serving request at URI /rest/... for example and another controller serving JSPs for the web. Or even as you stated a single controller which return HTML (via JSP) or JSON depending on the request. Have a look at https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc (old link, there might be a newer up to date link..)

Comment: i Thinks that is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer for more visibility ;)